# What formula should use in excel file

Tags: css, excel

I needed to remove the unused CSS classes from my styles.

So I went through all the pages and collected the unused css from each page and listed it in a excel file. Now I wanted to filter only the unused css class in the entire website.

What formula should I use here to solve my problem? If you need additional info, please let me know.

Comment: Confusing. You collected all the unused CSS and now you want to filter the unused CSS in Excel?

Comment: That has redundant value. Read the question once more. That list is not the final one!

Comment: If you are looking for a formula in Excel to remove duplicates you should show some part of the your Excel sheet here. But if your intention is to remove _unused CSS_ from your pages, then you got pretty good answers here.

Answer (score 0):

css lint is open source and mo betta http://csslint.net/